# Is it possible with PrintThis .js jquery plugin to send the PDF to storage in a file storage server Afterprint :function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Afterprint :function call and send to storage using ajax.

```
 $("#myText").printThis({
 afterPrint: function(){
    //your code to execute
   }
});
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible PrintThis plugin , print or save button click then save the pdf to file storage server , please share code   
#K J

Comment: user can print or save but all time before save it client pc or printer file also save my set located storage server in bihind #K J

Comment: what is solution save this pdf file in dms server using ajax jquery?
#K J

Comment: pleaase share a code example