# Is it possible with PrintThis .js jquery plugin to send the PDF to storage in a file storage server instead of printing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/#nada to send a PDF to a folder on my website instead of printing it.

My task is to save form data into a PDF and save the PDF in a folder on my website once the user submits. I like the way PrintThis .js  creates the PDF and sends it to print but I need it to send to my folder...maybe through Ajax jquery ?

[enter image description here][1]

details in picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agHee.png

Comment: First off, you are dealing with raw data correct? e.g. form inputs. what language are you running on your server? php? you are thinking about this wrong. You dont want to SEND a file to the server, you want to create a file on the server.

Comment: my web site show a html file in browser , this html file save as pdf file by jquery ajax   in my web site service api after create pdf using PrintThis .js  jquery plugin .#
Michael Mano

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible with PrintThis .js jquery plugin to send the PDF to storage in a file storage server Afterprint :function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346727/is-it-possible-with-printthis-js-jquery-plugin-to-send-the-pdf-to-storage-in-a)